# SQL Server 2000 query

Tags: sql-server-2000, distinct

I have a created a few tables containing multiple records from several users so I can simulate circumstances.

I created the following query:

```
SELECT 
    a.celid, a.callid, a.active, a.messagetext,
    b.jactive, a.cel_time, c.username, a.muserid 
FROM level2 a, calls b , login c 
WHERE a.callid = b.jid 
  AND a.muserid = c.loginid 
  AND b.jid = 92 
  AND a.win = 0 
  AND b.userid = 12 
ORDER BY 
    cel_time ASC
```

and got the following as result

```
545 92  2   hello1  2   2011-09-18 16:32:17.000 phil01  21
546 92  1   hello2  2   2011-09-18 16:42:38.000 phil01  21
547 92  2   hello3  2   2011-09-18 16:59:08.000 danny   16
548 92  1   hello4  2   2011-09-18 20:46:21.000 phil01  21
549 92  1   hello5  2   2011-09-18 20:47:16.000 phil01  21  
550 92  1   hello6  2   2011-09-19 19:32:15.000 phil01  21  
551 92  1   hello7  2   2011-09-19 19:34:14.000 phil01  21
```

but I actually want this result to be distinct on `muserid` and return only return two rows.

I have studied distinct value description but can not seem to get this accomplished.

How would I accomplish this?

Comment: Which two rows do you want it to return?  (I understand that you want one row for user id 21, and one row for user id 16, but which rows?  The earliest?  The most recent?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this SQL:

```
SELECT 
    a.celid, a.callid, a.active, a.messagetext,
    b.jactive, a.cel_time, c.username, a.muserid 
FROM level2 a
JOIN calls b ON a.callid = b.jid 
JOIN login c ON a.muserid = c.loginid 
JOIN 
  (SELECT l2.muserid, MAX(l2.cel_time) as max_time 
   FROM level2 l2 
   GROUP BY l2.muserid) d ON (d.muserid = a.muserid AND a.cel_time = d.max_time)
WHERE b.jid = 92 
  AND a.win = 0 
  AND b.userid = 12
```

Comment: thank you, it worked - I will study this further as I am sure I will come across similar circumstances.